# no clipping for two different meshes

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, mirror

I am trying to make it so that two different meshes stop clipping (overlapping each other). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It is unclear what you are asking. Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/164668/edit) your question and [add some images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: The 'clipping' checkbox is designed to keep you from moving geometry across the mirror axis. It also prevents you from moving geometry already on the axis off of it. What kind of behavior are you attempting to achieve with your two different objects?